# Junit test for boolean method

Tags: java, testing, junit

how can I create a test method using asseertEquals  for method  Boolean isEqual(Semester semester) with Boolean type in class Semester?

here is the code for class Semester and the junit  test for class Semester

#### Semester

```
public class Semester {
    private String year;
    private String name;

    public Semester() {
        year = null;
        name = null;
    }

    public Semester(String year, String name) {
        this.year = year;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean isEqual(Semester semestr) {
        return ((semestr.name.equals(this.name)) && (semestr.year
            .equals(this.year)));
    }

    public String getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

#### SemesterTest

```
public class SemesterTestCase1 {
    private Semester semster=new Semester("2014","Fall");

    @Test
    public void testIsEqual() {

    }

    @Test
    public void testGetYear() {
        assertEquals("2014",semster.getYear());
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetName() {
        assertEquals("Fall",semster.getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: `assertEquals(true, actualValue)` and `assertEquals(false, actualValue)` both work. There's also `assertTrue(actualValue)` and `assertFalse(actualValue)`. Did you take a look at the JavaDoc for the [`Asserts`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html) class? If those options don't work, please let us know why they don't work, and more importantly, what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: Don't forget to test for `NullPointerException`s.

Comment: You need to override `equals` instead of defining your own `isEqual` to use `assertEquals`.

Comment: @user2418306 Not necessarily. `equals` has very specific contracts it must obey, whereas a custom method like `isEqual` can do whatever it wants. There are definitely times you want one and not the other. For instance, let's say you have a `Person` object with an `id` field as well as name and dob. It probably makes sense for `equals` to _only_ check `id`, since if you have a `Map<Person, Job>` you want to uniquely identify each person by id. But you may also want to check that two `Person` objects have all the same values, for which a custom `isEqual` is more appropriate.

Comment: @yshavit Can you name rules of the equals contract which custom method can violate? If in your domain you can guarantee that `Person.id` is unique what is the point of compering rest of the fields? If not your Map won't work correctly.

Comment: @user2418306 A custom rule can violate _any_ of the [rules for `equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)), since it defines its own contract. Probably the most relevant one is that it must be consistent with `hashCode()`. As for `id` equality, as an example, what if you've got two `Map<Person, Job>`s, one from a month ago and one from now, and you want to find people who have changed jobs: `!m1.get(person).equals(m2.get(person))`. If a person changed their name in that month, you still want to find them in both maps.

Comment: @user2418306 But, now that I think of it, we're getting into general-discussion-category, so if you want to continue it, I'd suggest starting a chat and inviting me to it. :)

Answer (score 4):

First, I would change your `isEqual()`:

```
public boolean isEqual(Semester semestr) {
        boolean flag = false;
        if (this.name != null && this.year != null 
            && this.semestr.name != null && this.semestr.year != null ){
        flag = ((semestr.name.equals(this.name)) && (semestr.year
            .equals(this.year)));
          }
           return flag;
    }
```

Try with assertTrue instead of assertEquals:

```
 @Test
    public void testIsEqual() {
    Semester semsterTest = new Semester("2014","Fall");
    boolean res = this.semster.isEqual(semsterTest);
    assertTrue(res);
    }
```

I recommend you using `assertTrue` and `assertFalse` when you want testing boolean methods.

Comment: Fwiw, I _don't_ like `assertTrue` and `assertFalse`, because they don't give very helpful messages. Those overloads just basically tell you there's an error. If you do something like `assertTrue("fall 2014", res)` then your message will be unhelpfully just "fall 2014." If you use `assertEquals`, then the error message will be "fall 2014: expected <true> but was <false>", which to me is very helpful.

Comment: If you use `assertTrue("fall 2014", res)` and the test fail, you know that expected was true (by `assertTrue`) and that res was `false` (because if it were true the test were correct) isn't it? You are correct when you say that `assertEquals` give more helpful message, but to read the code, `assertTrue` and `assertFalse` give you a fast idea about what are you testing. I don't think that `assertEquals` give you a lot of advantages. I think is opinion based. Anyway thank you for your comment :)

Comment: when I use this way for the default constructer                                     private Semester semster=new Semester(null,null);                                   I get an error with a null pointer exception

Comment: If you really want to see "expected <true> but was <false>" you can use the Hamcrest extensions (bundled depending on your version of JUnit) `assertThat(condition, equalTo(true))`

Comment: @Abdulla, this is a problem of your method `isEqual()`. I consider that two semester with some variable null isn't equals. Also, I recommend you to write another test `testIsNotEqual()` to check with an `assertFalse` if you `isEqual` works well with two differents semesters. I've edit the answer with a possible new `isEqual()`.

Comment: @Shondeslitch Yup, definitely an opinion! I like to be able to see the expected value right from the test failure, before I even drill down the code. And yes, I could write more in the description, like `assertTrue("expected fall 2014 equality to be true", res)`, but at that point what have I saved vs `assertEquals("fall 2014 equality", true, res)`? Similarly with the Hamcrest solution. Basically, I find `assertEquals` to be a good balance between giving me a helpful message, and less typing on my part. But yes, it's totally opinion, which is why I put it as a comment and not an answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

There are three things to address with this code.

First, there already exists a method in which two objects can compare equivalent with each other called `equals`.  You want to override that method instead of creating your own equality method.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object otherSemester) {
    // your code here
}
```

Second, your method is **not null tolerant**.  If one were to pass `null` to that method, you'd get a wonderful `NullPointerException`.  This needs to be addressed by ensuring that the object you've passed in is not null.

```
if(semester != null) {
    // logic based on semester being non-null
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Lastly, your test could do with a bit of a rewrite.  You'd want to define several cases:

- Equal semesters
- Not equal semesters
- Null
- Non-null but non-inflated semesters (somehow passing `null` to the constructor)

While there are too many cases for me to enumerate here, they can be tested with [Hamcrest matchers](https://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/wiki/Tutorial).

```
assertThat(semester.equals(otherSemester), is(false));
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying assertEquals, you can try assertTrue.

```
@Test
public void testIsEqual() {
assertTrue(isEqual(semester));
}
```

assertTrue is specially used to check boolean values.

Answer (score 0):

For Boolean testing in Junit it would be better to use assertTrue / assertFalse

```
@Test
public void testIsEqual() {
assertTrue(isEqual(semester)); // to check value is true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use assertj fluent assertions which will do the job:

```html
assertThat(boolean_expression).isTrue()
assertThat(boolean_expression).isFalse()
assertThat(boolean_expression).isEqualTo(another_boolean_expression)
```

More on http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/